# How to convert timezone name to shortname in ruby

Tags: ruby, timezone

Is there a way to convert timezones like "America/Los_Angeles" to timezone shortname "PDT" in ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The abbreviations are typically contextual - so "PDT" only applies *while daylight saving time is in operation*.

Judging by [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime), if you format a `Time` with `strftime` and use a format string of `%Z`, you should get the time zone abbreviation.

Personally I dislike using the abbreviations, given that they're ambiguous and can cause a lot of confusion. (I've seen people using "PST" year-round, for example, referring to "7/20/2012 9:00 PST" for example - a date/time which makes no sense.) That's a different matter though :)

Comment: If it only works in daylight saving time then it will not fulfil my application requirement. Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth noting that this method will return the abbreviation but won't differentiate between the conflicting abbreviations in Australia. For example, Adelaide is in Australian "CST" timezone which conflicts with the "CST" used in North America, which can trip you up depending on the technology stack used (PostgreSQL is one).

Comment: @douglasr: Indeed - hence the "given that they're ambiguous" bit.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I totally missed that sentence somehow. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

More explicit answer:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone("America/Los_Angeles").strftime('%Z')
```

Comment: Fails in following scenario
2.2.2 :059 > Time.now.in_time_zone("Indiana (East)").strftime('%Z')
=> "EDT" 
2.2.2 :060 > Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").strftime('%Z')
=> "EDT"

Comment: Strange.  Are you sure that isn't a bug with Rails?

Comment: I cant say if its a bug or not. Whats happening is its failing in case of day light saving. So its also debatable that its a fail or not. Ruby uses utc_offset to tell us what timezone it is. I would say its a fail or not is based on what USA uses as a standard. If they use EDT for Indiana (East) during day light saving then its not a bug but if they use EST both during day light saving and normal days then its a fail.